# Using two different Models in controller action for POST and GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have "Add" method in one of my controllers in MVC project. On a normal "GET" I want to return Strongly-Typed object of type `CaseEditModel` and on POST verb I want the view to return an object of type `Case` to the controller. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on a get your Add action can return CaseEditModel to the view and on a post the argument for the Add action can be of type Case.  On the post the model binder will try and bind to whatever you put in for an argument.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var caseEdit = new CaseEditModel();
    return View(caseEditModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Case caseIn)
{

}
```

Comment: The caveat here is that you'll need to use different Views, as each view will be strongly typed to either `Case` or `CaseEditModel`, unless you make them both inherit from a common parent, but you'll loose any specialized properties.

Comment: Won't the model binder attempt to bind to caseIn regardless of it's type?

Comment: I mean the aspx file.  If you inherit from `ViewPage<T>` you need to specify the type of `T`.  For the Get you're going to want `CaseEditModel` for the post you're going to want `Case`.

Comment: Assuming the post `Add` returns a View that is and doesn't redirect (which it should).

Comment: Simplify and return CaseInput on the get and CaseInput on the post, then map CaseInput to your domain object Case, if that's what your aiming for here.

Answer (score -2):

The Request object has the requesttype property to do just that:

```
if (Request.RequestType == "GET")
{
     // do CaseEditModel here
}
else if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
{
     // do Case here
}
```