# Different models for Get and Post - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

As I understand from the question below it should be possible to use different models for Get and Post actions. But somehow I'm failing to achieve just that.

What am I missing?

Related question: [Using two different Models in controller action for POST and GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372905/using-two-different-models-in-controller-action-for-post-and-get)

**Model**

```
public class GetModel
{
    public string FullName;
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
}

public class PostModel
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View(new GetModel {Id = 12, Name = "Olson", FullName = "Peggy Olson"});
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(PostModel postModel)
    {
        if(postModel.Name == null)
            throw new Exception("PostModel was not filled correct");
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.GetModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your view referencing class name... remove those "dsads" dummy characters. You're probably getting an error that model class is unknown.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: What are you missing? You are missing to include the error you are getting in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the missing error - I forgot to say that the purpose was to not throw an exception in Edit method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your models aren't using proper accessors so model binding doesn't work. Change them to this and it should work:

```
public class GetModel
{
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PostModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought those classes in question were missing them for simplicity reasons but were otherwise everyday properties. :) *Never trust example code to be much different from original*

Answer (score 7):

### A bit of clarification

GET and POST controller actions can easily use whatever types they need to. Actually we're not talking about models here. Model is a set of classes/types that represent some application state/data. Hence *application* or *data* model.

What we're dealing here are:

- view model types
- action method parameter types

So your application model is still the same. And `GetModel` and `PostModel` are just two classes/types in this model. They're not model per-se.

### Different types? Of course we can!

In your case you're using a view model type `GetModel` and then pass its data to `PostModel` action parameter. Since these two classes/types both have properties with same matching names, default model binder will be able to populate `PostModel` properties. If property names wouldn't be the same, you'd have to change the view to rename inputs to reflect POST action type property names.

You could as well have a view with `GetModel` type and then post action with several different prameters like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Person person, IList<Address> addresses)
{
    ...
}
```

Or anything else. You'll just have to make sure that post data can be bound to these parameters and their type properties...